# What does the SSAS setting None in AggregateFunction do?

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-table, cube

As I understand Microsoft's explanation setting the AggregateFunction of a measure to "None" should null out the value unless you are viewing the data at the lowest possible level.  (i.e. the data element is a copy of the value in one exact cell in the cube).

I've created a fact table at the grain product id and sales date, and have set AggregateFunction property of a few measures (they are percentages of some sort) to "None", and I nulls at every level in the cube, even the product/sales date level (I am using Excel to connect to the cube and drilling through a pivot table).

I'm sure that there is something simple that I am missing, but I don't quite see what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Aggregate Function of a Measure is set to 'None', SSAS does not calculate the measure for the 'All' member in any dimension. Put in other words, we will have **only leaf-level values** for measures and that too only for dimensions that are directly linked to that fact.

You can find more elaborate explanation in [this post](http://sornanara.blogspot.in/2012/10/ssas-understanding-non-aggregate.html).

Comment: Thank you.  Having this information helped me dig further into my setup and figure out what was going on.

Comment: Thanks It is wonderful demo but for end users, displaying keys are not good. How can we display dim description (like RegionName) with no aggregation?