# no aggregation with descriptive values

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-table, cube

I have applied no aggregation in measure and with all the key attributes which showing results. but for end users, I want to display these results with attribute description (e.g. CustomerName rather than CustomerID)

Anyone please suggest how can this will be implemented?

I have successfully implemented this:
[What does the SSAS setting None in AggregateFunction do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953490/what-does-the-ssas-setting-none-in-aggregatefunction-do])

Comment: There is no question that I can see here. You describe two things that you've done, then ask how to implement them, and then list another thing that you've done.

Comment: I want to display no aggregation results with Description information (Dim).

Comment: Anyone can help me on this please?